# i3-radius dependancy issues

Tags: apt, package-management, i3-wm

## The issue

Installing from source (https://github.com/terroo/i3-radius)

I cloned that repo went to the folder and ran `./configure`
everything is going to plan but it needs some dependencies.
Okay no problem I just install it with
`sudo apt install 'whatever'`
I install the package and run `./configure` again. This loop repeats again and again.

## What I need

What I need is some sort of package list I could find to just install everything with APT but I can't seem to find one. Another solution is installing it in another way that I haven't thought of, anything helps here...

Comment: There's a working PPA for that (https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Installation) you don't need to compile.

Comment: I agree with @ChanganAuto - why not use a PPA? There are [official directions for that](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Installation#ubuntu)...